# access the clicked li element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have dropdown like UL in my view with ng-click. When I select an Item in the list it is not being selected. what am I doing wrong.

HTML :

```
<div class="btn-group" id="divWotcStatuss" style="display: inline-block;" ng-show="clickedStatus">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span id="h2HeaderCompany" style="color:navy; font-size:25px;text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0 1px 2px;">
                            {{statusById.EvalstatusTitle}}
                            </span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li ng-repeat="status in Enums.StatusForDropdown" >
                                <a ng-click="clickedStatus=status.EvalStatusId; FilterEmpsList()">
                                    {{status.EvalstatusTitle}}
                                  </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

JS :

```
    $scope.GetStatusById = function () {  

        $scope.statusById = $scope.Enums.StatusForDropdown.find(function (el, idx) {
    return el.EvalStatusId === $scope.clickedStatus;
        })
    };


WotcDashBoardModule.constant('Enums', {
    StatusForDropdown:[
                        {EvalStatusId: '0', EvalstatusTitle: 'WOTC Screened'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '5', EvalstatusTitle: 'WOTC Pre-Qualified'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '2', EvalstatusTitle: 'Submitted All Docs'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '11', EvalstatusTitle: 'Submitted Missing Docs'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '10', EvalstatusTitle: 'Not Submitted'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '3', EvalstatusTitle: 'Employees Approved'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '9', EvalstatusTitle: 'Employees Denied'},
                        {EvalStatusId: '4', EvalstatusTitle: 'Request For Additional Info'}
                      ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by being selected but I'll take my best guess and you can do the rest.

You have a method in ng-click FilterEmpsList(), I would pass the value to that method like so, FilterEmpsList(status.EvalStatusId), then in that method you can assign the value to some other variable like this.

```
var FilterEmpsList = function (value) { 
    $scope.SelectedValue = value; 
}
```

Then you can use $scope.SelectedValue as you had intended in the first place.